# Django / SQL / Проверка

Tags: sql, django, sqlite

Подскажите как правильно сделать проверку,мне нужно проверить есть ли в базе такая пара (ip и user_agent)если нет то добавить

view.py

```
def all(request):
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if x_forwarded_for:
    ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
else:
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    user_agent = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
    name_host = request.META.get('SERVER_PORT')
    method = request.META.get('REQUEST_METHOD')


data = {"ip": ip,"user_agent": user_agent,"name_host": name_host,"method": method }
return render(request, 'poll/all.html', context=data)
```

model.py

```
class Unique_set(models.Model):
     UserAgent = models.TextField()
     IP_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.IP_user
```

Comment: *мне нужно проверить есть ли в базе такая пара (ip и user_agent)если нет то добавить* А если есть?

Comment: то открыть другую страницу

Comment: А если нет - добавить и остаться на этой? или добавить, а затем перейти на ТУ ЖЕ "другую страницу"?

Comment: добавить и остаться на этой) Извините за неточность

Comment: Ну тогда запросите количество записей с указанными параметрами: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE ip='$ip' AND user_agent='$user_agent'`. Вернётся ноль - нет такой буквы, не ноль - есть. Ну а дальше вульгарный IF().

Comment: @Akina Ваш ответ может и правильный, но это Django. Думаю, тут стоит работать через ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для проверки на существование может подойти такое условие:

```py
if Unique_set.objects.filter(UserAgent=user_agent, IP_user=ip).exists():
    ...
```

Чтобы создать объект, используйте такую инструкцию:

```py
Unique_set.objects.create(UserAgent=user_agent, IP_user=ip)
```

---

**UPD:**
Оптимальным решением будет использовать метод `get_or_create`:

```py
Unique_set.objects.get_or_create(UserAgent=user_agent, IP_user=ip)
```

Вернётся кортеж, где 2 элемент (индекс `1`) показывает создался ли объект или уже присутствовал. Это может пригодиться в каком-либо условии.